# Give Python subprocess a terminal to redirect stdout/stderr

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker-compose, subprocess

I want to use a Python subprocess to run docker-compose while keeping the ANSI escape codes in its output. A simplified version of the script looks like this:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

args = ["docker-compose", "--ansi", "tty", "up", "-d"]

with Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line.decode("utf-8"), end="")
```

*Note that from docker-compose v2.17.3 onward the `"tty"` must be replaced with `"always"` ([Bug on Github](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10439)).*

I want to catch/redirect all output. Docker-compose outputs to stderr by default, so the `stderr=STDOUT` is necessary. However, since ["compose requires a terminal"](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/10487#issuecomment-1517350673) executing this Python program fails.

How can I run the subprocess while catching its output, when it requires a terminal?

I use the following docker-compose.yml for testing:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
```